# MongoDB: Search by id and other properties

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongo-shell, spring-mongodb

I have Mongo document

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e4c4c0935f4115dfc5540c2"),
    "code" : "ABC"
}
```

and as per other SO threads looks like doing regex on Id is not possible as it has hexString. So I am querying with `ObjectId`

```
@Query("{'code': {$regex : ?0, $options: 'i'}, '_id': ?1}")
Page<Pack> findByCodeAndId(String code, ObjectId objectId, Pageable pageable);
```

now as the query paramets or optional, I have check if the passed id is valid before converting it to `ObjectId`

```
ObjectId objectId = null;
    if (ObjectId.isValid(id)) {
        objectId = new ObjectId(id);
    }
```

now for the request `{code: null, id: null}`  I want to bring first 10 documents as these are optional but the query is not working when it is passed `null` as `ObjectId`

Also tried `ObjectId objectId = new ObjectId()` but it is generating a random `haxString` and giving empty records when `id` is `null`

Comment: Just omit `_id`? `{code: null}` or `{}`?

Comment: @willis I didn't not get it. You mean to dynamically omit ```_id``` if it not passed? then I will have to write two different  findBy methods or am I misunderstanding here

Comment: Yes, dynamically omit it. Or do something like `{_id: id ? ObjectId(id) : {$exists: true}}` if you want a one-liner.